# XSLT when otherwise loop not working properly

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to represent with XSLT a table which input fields can be `text` or `number`. I have in the XML a tag which contains the columns and rows number. Into `headerName` tag, I have the header info of the table.

This is an example of my XML:

```
<elements>
       <element type="TABLE">
            <id>table2</id>
            <order>49</order>
            <table>
                <colNumber>2</colNumber>
                <headerName>
                    <amount>false</amount>
                    <value>Header1</value>
                </headerName>
                <headerName>
                    <amount>true</amount>
                    <value>Header2</value>
                </headerName>
                <rowNumber>2</rowNumber>
            </table>
        </element>
</elements>
```

Now, the XSLT that I'm using is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="elements/element">
    <xsl:if test="@type='TABLE'">
        <div data-order="{order}" id="{id}">
            <table class="table table-bordered mt-lg">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="table/headerName">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:variable name="rows" select="table/rowNumber/text()"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="table/colNumber/text()"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="amount" select="table/headerName/amount/text()"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="(//node())[$rows &gt;= position()]">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="(//node())[$cols &gt;= position()]">
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="$amount = 'false'">
                                            <input type="text"/>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <input type="number"/>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And my expected output is this:

```
<div data-order="49" id="table2">
    <table class="table table-bordered mt-lg">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Header1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Header2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text"></input></td>
                <td><input type="number"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text"></input></td>
                <td><input type="number"></input></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm not seeing where is the mistake, I have tried with xpath expressions but I am always getting `<input type="text"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the variable `amount` you do so before your `xsl:for-each` statements, so it is only ever going to be set to the value of the first `table/headerName` in the XML You really need to move the declaration inside the inner most `xsl:for-each`, as it looks like you want it set based on the current column number.

However, you would then need to take into account you won't be positioned on the `element` element at that point, so you would need to store a reference to `element` in a variable first, so you can access it in inside the `xsl:for-each`

Try this XSLT fragment

```
<tbody>
    <xsl:variable name="rows" select="table/rowNumber/text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="table/colNumber/text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="node" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="(//node())[$rows &gt;= position()]">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="(//node())[$cols &gt;= position()]">
                <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()" />
                <xsl:variable name="amount" select="$node/table/headerName[position() = $position]/amount/text()"/>
                <td>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$amount = 'false'">
                            <input type="text"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <input type="number"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tbody>
```

I am guessing you are aware your XSLT will fail if the `rowNumber` or `colNumber` exceeds the number of nodes in the XML....

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, thanks a lot for the explanation, I didn't see it before.